# Refreshing Jtable after deleting object with hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, swing, jtable

populating table with initial data:

```
additionsTable.setModel(new AdditionalDocsTableModel(addDocuments));
```

constructor of the model:

```
public AdditionalDocsTableModel(List<MyDocument> docs) {
        this.docs = docs;
    }
```

Here's code in AbstractTableModel for deleting object from table:

```
      public void delObjectAtRow(int row){
             MyDocument doc= docs.get(row);
             MainFrame.session.beginTransaction();
             MainFrame.session.update(doc);
             MainFrame.session.delete(doc);
             MainFrame.session.beginTransaction().commit();
        }
```

calling method:

```
private void deletePopupItemActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        // TODO add your handling code here:
         if (additionsTable.getSelectedRow() > -1) {

            AdditionalDocsTableModel t = (AdditionalDocsTableModel) additionsTable.getModel();
            t.delObjectAtRow(additionsTable.getSelectedRow());


        }
}
```

How do i populate model with new data ? Right now i cant retrieve new data from session. i tried load and update. but receive same stuff as before deleting. Any help would be appreciated. thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call one of the fire methods of the base class to notify JTable that the data has changed.

Comment: thanks for answer. But how do i get new data from session to populate model?

Comment: Note: Unless this is a local db consider to use an EJB (remote service) call to access the db rather than directly access the db.