# Java Hibernate wont refresh jTable

Tags: java, mysql, swing, hibernate

I have a problem in refreshing my `jtable` after entering, deleting or updating data. I need to re-run app to see new imported/edited data. I am working in Hibernate. Tried `repaint(); revalidate(); flush()`; Please help me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Refreshing Jtable after deleting object with hibernate?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8078089/refreshing-jtable-after-deleting-object-with-hibernate)

Comment: highlighted the code

Comment: event from Hibernate (util.List) doesn't notify EDT, you have to use good designed TableModel with proper notifiers inside models definition

Comment: I just screen recorded problem.. if u guys find time please take a look (sry 4 bad eng) 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fhDU-en4q3I